# Eclipse returning "calls" instead of "call hierarchy"

Tags: eclipse

I've been working win the same Eclipse instance for a long time now, and ctrl + alt + h has always yielded "all methods calling the current method", aka "call hierarchy". However, as of yesterday, it is yielding "all methods being called inside of current method", which is useless. I've tried RMC on the method and selecting "call hierarchy", and also using ctrl + alt + h, but both return the undesired results.

Anybody has ever experienced this? Any idea on how to fix it? I would like to avoid re-installing eclipse just because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is most probably using the "*Callee Hierarchy*" mode.

Try switching it to the "Caller Hierarchy" mode by clicking on the arrow in the top right corner of the view.

[image]